# How to check if radio button is checked and compare its value in if condition?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have tried everything and still no result is coming out

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="demoForm" id="demoForm">
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Demo: Get Value Onclick</legend>

      <p><h4>Which one is markup Language ?</h4>&nbsp;
        </br>
          <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="CSS" /> CSS</label> </br>
          <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="JAVASCRIPT" checked="checked" /> JAVASCRIPT</label> </br>
          <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="HTML" /> HTMl</label> </br>
          <button type="button" onClick="calcScore()" name="button">do</button>
      </p>

      </fieldset>
    </form>


function calcScore() {
  var Enter = document.getElementsByName('#size');
  let i = 0;
  while (i < Enter.length) {
    if (Enter[i].checked == "true" && Enter[i].value === "HTML") {
           console.log("correct");
      }
      i = i + 1;
    }

};
```

It is expected to log “correct” in console if the HTML radio button is checked

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByName` takes just the name as a parameter, not a selector (so it's `"size"` not `"#size"`):

```
var Enter = document.getElementsByName('size');
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Changes will make it work :

1.Change `getElementsByName` selector to `('size')` .

2.The `Enter[i].checked` returns a `boolean` value not `string`. So Should check the result in this way : `Enter[i].checked && Enter[i].value === "HTML"`

Answer (score 0):

For dom elements better to use **forEach**

Check this

```
function calcScore() {
  const Enter = document.getElementsByName('size');

  Enter.forEach(el => {
    if (el.value === "HTML" && el.checked) {
      console.log("correct")
    }
  })
};
```

or **for** loop

```
function calcScore() {
  const Enter = document.getElementsByName('size');

  for(let i = 0; i < Enter.length; i++) {
    if (Enter[i].value === "HTML" && Enter[i].checked) {
      console.log("correct")
    }
  };
};
```